# I am getting error while installing json by gem using Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, installation, windows-7-x64

1. I have Downloaded Ruby 2.1.5
2. cmd check command: `ruby -v` returns result: ruby 2.1.5
3. Downloaded DevKit file from here [DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx.exe](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)
4. Extract DevKit to path `C:\Ruby\DevKit`
5. `cd C:\Ruby\DevKit`
6. `ruby dk.rb init`
7. `ruby dk.rb review`
8. `ruby dk.rb install`

Up till this point, everything is okay but from now onward I am getting error.

I am passing from command

cmd : `gem install json`

and getting following error.

```
could not find a valid gem 'json'<>=0), here is why:
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/- SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify faild(https:api.rubygem.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty common issue with rubygems recently changing their certificate authority.

A detailed breakdown of the issue, and how to resolve it can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88).